# How to force start ubuntu without keyboard

Tags: installation

Old toshiba xp laptop will not load cannot be started in safe mode or boot Ubuntu from disc as arrow keys do not work, any ideas appreciated even if it means wiping computer with another program,
 i have no windows discs want it to be stand alone linux computer how do i get linux to  force start installation

Comment: If I remember correctly, you don't need arrow keys as long as you're accepting defaults.  Just enter, tab, and enough keys to enter a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in an external keyboard.  You can likely buy an old PS2 or USB keyboard for less than $10 from a garage sale or Goodwill or something, if you don't already have one on hand.

Comment: Like your thinking will try that first, any other ideas if it does not work????

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could also try taking apart the laptop, and seeing if you can repair the broken keys. Or buy a replacement keyboard, or another laptop of the same make and model that's broken in some other way to swap the keyboard out.  I've never taken apart a Toshiba before, so I don't know how easy they are to repair.